# Get CurrentRegion only in vertical direction

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to write a UDF (user defined function, aka. macro) that will be used in each of the green cells. In this function/macro in want to get the length of the longest string in the framed cells next to my current group of green cells. In order to do this in the macro I need to determine a range that represents all of the framed cells next to the current cell. (This calculation should result the same range object for each cell in one green group but a different one from group to group.) How would you get this Range?

[image]

My first try was this:

```
Range(Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp),_
      Application.Caller.Offset(0, -1).End(xlDown))
```

But this

- doesn't work
- would give false range if the caller cell is the uppermost or lowermost cell of a group.

I would need something like `ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).CurrentRegion`, but in the vertical direction only.

Comment: There is an issue with using `CurrentRegion` in UDFs http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsj.htm

Comment: It's not clear how you set the range of green cells and what you want to do sequentially. If there is data in the green cell or if it is a number or a character, we need more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function findlongest()

Dim fullcolumn() As Variant
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long, j As Long, k As Long
Dim tmax As Long
tmax = 0
With Application.Caller
    lastrow = .Parent.Cells(.Parent.Rows.Count, .Column - 1).End(xlUp).Row
    fullcolumn = .Parent.Range(.Parent.Cells(1, .Column - 1), .Parent.Cells(lastrow, .Column - 1)).Value
    For j = .Row To 1 Step -1
        If fullcolumn(j, 1) = "" Then
            j = j + 1
            Exit For
        ElseIf j = 1 Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
    For i = .Row To UBound(fullcolumn, 1)
        If fullcolumn(i, 1) = "" Then
            i = i - 1
            Exit For
        ElseIf i = UBound(fullcolumn, 1) Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i

    'to get the range
    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Parent.Range(.Parent.Cells(j, .Column - 1), Parent.Cells(i, .Column - 1))
    'then do what you want with rng


    'but since you already have the values in an array use that instead.
    'It is quciker to iterate and array than the range.
    For k = j To i
        If Len(fullcolumn(k, 1)) > tmax Then tmax = Len(fullcolumn(k, 1))
    Next k
findlongest = tmax
End With
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: What is `Application.Caller.Parent` ?

Comment: it ensures that we are looking at the correct sheet when doing the calculations and not the active sheet at that time.

Comment: Oh, thanks. But, actually, I would only need to get the described Range somehow.. :\

Comment: This does exactly what you asked.  it finds the longest string in the current range in the column one over.

Comment: @Greenberet see edit for how to get the range from the code.  I do not recommend it as iterating an array is much quicker than iterating a range.

Comment: Ok, I have managed to understand your solution! :) It really does what I wanted. Now that you have modified the code not to use ALL the cells in the column to the left I will happily use it. Thanks!

Comment: @Greenberet if this answered your question please consider marking it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Are you after something like the code below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetLeftRange()

Dim myRng As Range

Set myRng = ActiveCell.Offset(, -1).CurrentRegion

Debug.Print myRng.Address

End Sub
```

**Note**: `ActiveCell` is one of the cells you marked as green.

Comment: Yes, but as far as I know CurrentRegion works in every direction so this would result in a range that contains the green cells as well. I would like to get only the framed cells as a range.

Comment: @Greenberet do you have values or text in the green cells ? do you want it to return a single column on the left side ?#

Comment: The UDF itself in all of the green cells will result in values. I want a Range that represents the framed cells.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of setting each range using Area.

```
Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range
    Dim rngA As Range, rng As Range

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    With Ws
        Set rngDB = .Range("a1", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

        Set rngA = rngDB.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues)
        For Each rng In rngA.Areas
            rng.Offset(, 1).Select '<~~ select is not required but is intended to be visualized
        Next rng
    End With
End Sub
```

[image]